# I had make a chekcbox itemtemplate in gridview which will have only one check, its working fine. But now i want to color the selected row

Tags: javascript

```
function SingleCheckboxCheck(ob) {
    var gridvalue = ob.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var inputs = gridvalue.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (ob.checked && inputs[i] != ob && inputs[i].checked) {
                inputs[i].checked = false;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

<asp:GridView ID="grdHolidayDetails" runat="server" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
DataKeyNames="" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" ShowHeader="true" CssClass="box-table-a td"
>

```
                    <asp:TemplateField >
                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:CheckBox ID="delholdate" runat="server" onclick="SingleCheckboxCheck(this)" />
                         </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>

              </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

A single check is working fine, but cannot toggle the color in the row, I want to change and revert the color with the checkbox check and uncheck`

Comment: Can you please add your complete code so we can check the HTML structure to provide you with the best possible solution?

Comment: if (ob.checked) {

            //    ob.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#88AAFF';} here color are fixed while changing check

Comment: Add your complete code to the question.